# Prove that simple graph $G$ is orientable

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I am a student in an introductory class for graph theory and this question is on our first homework assignment and I don't know where to start to prove the following:

> Suppose that $n \geq 3$ and a simple graph G has $n$ vertices and at
>   least $(n^2 - 3n + 6)/2$ edges. Prove that G is orientable.

Thank you for your time. Any hints or help will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: A graph g is orientable if it is the underlying graph of a strongly connected digraph. A digraph is strongly connected if for all vertices $v$ and $w$ there exists a walk $v-w$.

Answer (score 2):

By Robin's Theorem, a graph is orientable if and only if it is connected and has no bridge.

So try to prove:

Step 1: Any graphs with $(n^2 - 3n + 6)/2$ edges is connected.

Step 2: Any graphs with $(n^2 - 3n + 6)/2$ edges cannot have bridges.

Step 1 is pretty standard and easy. For step 2, assume by contradiction that $G$ has a bridge $b$ then, by erasing this bridge you get a graph with two disjoint components, one with $k$ vertices and the other one with $n-k$ vertices.

What is the maximum number of vertices in each component?

Comment: To be more specific of the step 2, here the maximum number of edges from 2 components plus 1 due to the bridge is $f(n,k)=\frac{k \left(k - 1\right)}{2} + \frac{\left(- k + n\right) \left(- k + n - 1\right)}{2} + 1$. It has the maximum when $k=n-1$ or $1$ (Here $k=n$ is impossible because of the bridge). Then $f(n,n-1)=\frac{\left(n - 2\right) \left(n - 1\right)}{2} + 1$ and $g(n)=f(n,n-1)-\frac{n^{2}-3 n + 6}{2}=-1$.

Comment: This means the edges of the disconnected graph $E(G') \le f(n,n-1)$ is impossible to get from "any graphs with $\frac{n^{2}-3 n + 6}{2}$ edges with one bridge", which also implying more than one bridges.

Comment: 2. For the step 1, the maximum edge number of disconnected graph with $n$ vertices can be got by removing edges from the complete graph $K_n$. To disconnect one vertex, we at least need to remove $n-1$ edges which is the above $f(n,n-1)$. By the above proof, it is impossible to get from "any graphs with $\frac{n^{2}-3 n + 6}{2}$ edges with one bridge", so the graph can't be disconnected. Please point out errors if any. Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

A few hints in addition to @Birch_SL.

> How many edges does a complete graph have? How close is that to the number of edges your graph has?

If the graph isn't orientable, what does that mean?

> We can try to tease out the structure that Birch_SL is assuming to exist. Namely, in any given orientation, there is a vertex $v$ that has no path to some $w$. Consider the set of all vertices accessible from $v$ and the set of those not. What do the edges between these sets look like? Could you come up with another orientation that is strongly connected (be careful here)?

Finally,

> What's the only way to not come up with an orientation that isn't strongly connected? How many edges must be missing?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that given graph (with the bunch of properties) is non-orientable, with more than or equal to 3 vertices.

As we know, from one of the definitons, stated in class, is that the simple graph G is not orientable, if it contains a bridge.

Now, let's construct such a graph:

Let's take for our proof simple graph, which contains two 3-vertex cycles, joined by one bridge. That graph has no problems with properties stated in the givens.

So the number of edges is $$m=m_1+m_2+1=n_1+n_2+1=3+3+1=7$$, such that $m_1,m_2,n_1,n_2$ are number of edges of first cycle,--||--||--of second cycle, number of vertices of first cycle and second, respectively.

Now, lets plug in total amount of vertices (6) into the formulae, which is in the given.

$$m={n^2−3n+6\over 2}=24/2=12$$

Since the number of edges of our non-orientable graph is less than calculated by formulae, so our statement that simple graph with $n\geq 3$ vertices has bridges => It is false statement, that simple graph with $n\geq 3$ vertices is non-orientable.

Therefore the graph with such properties is orientable.

---

---

Feel free to comment my proof, if you have better ideas.

Answer (score -1):

First thing which come to my mind is to suppose that this is non-orientable graph.

So if we suppose that this is non-orientable, then it follows to 2 cases (maybe more):

1) It is a path graph.
2) It has a bridges in it (so cycles, as well).

What is the number of edges it should have, if it is a path graph?
What if it has bridges+cycles?

Keep in mind it is simple graph, so no loops and multiple edges.